# is it possible to using InkWell in CustomScrollView in flutter

Tags: flutter

When I am embedded InkWell in CustomScrollView like this:

```
child: SizedBox(
                height: 500.0,
                child: CustomScrollView(slivers: <Widget>[
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () => {},
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text(
                          item.subName == "" ? "Comment" : item.subName,
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5.copyWith(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  SliverPadding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
                    sliver: viewService.buildComponent("articlelist"),
                  )
                ]),
              ),
            ),
```

shows this error:

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4345 pos 14: 'owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  CustomScrollView file:///Users/dolphin/Documents/GitHub/cruise-open/lib/src/page/channel/channeldetail_component/view.dart:96:24
====================================================================================================
```

should I use InkWell in CustomScrollView? CustomScrollView could only use sliver component? what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping `InkWell` in `SliverToBoxAdapter`

Comment: I have tried and fix this problem.@moneer alhashim

Comment: Does not work for me. Get `A $runtimeType expected a child of type $ChildType but received a child of type ${child.runtimeType}.`